# Conditionally enable member function of base class

Tags: c++

I have some classes similar to:

```
class A {
    void func();
};

class B1 : public A {
    using A::func;
};

class B2 : public A {
    void func();
};
```

Because class `B1` and `B2` in my project share most things, I want to make them as a common class that is distinguished by a template parameter:

```
class A {
    void func();
};

template <bool Use = false>
class B : public A {
    using A::func; // how can I activate this only if Use is true
};
```

How can I activate `using A::func;` only if Use is true?

Comment: `using` directives cannot be conditionally in scope, like that. Additionally, this `using` declaration is not accomplishing anything anyway. It would only make a difference if its class also had a `func()`. What do you expect `B1`'s `using` declaration to accomplish, in the example above?

Comment: `std::conditional` makes up for types. What is your use-case?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have a matrix class, non-owning view class, non-owning read-only const view class, and the base of all of them (say, ```MatrixBase```) I want to enable using MatrixBase::operator+= and its friends only for non-const views and non-const matrices.

Comment: A span-like entity?

Comment: Sort of, but my ```MatrixView``` works for iterating over submatrices. (That is, if you take the upper 2x2 submatrix of {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}} and iterate over it, it outputs 1,2,4,5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a specialization:

```
template<bool Use>
class B : public A {};

template<>
class B<false> {};
```

If the rest of the class is common, you can join them:

```
template<bool Use>
class C : public B<Use>
{
    int i;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try specializations.

```
template <bool Use = false>
class B : public A {
};

template <>
class B<true> : public A {
    using A::func; // activate this only if Use is true
};
```